# clearing multiple text fields at once

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to figure out the code for clearing multiple text fields at once. I know that there is another question like this with answers but could I get a little more information or code examples. I have 16 text fields in my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) methods, specifically, [textFieldShouldClear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:).  This is called when someone taps the little `x` in the text field.  I am going to give you a way to clear all textfields when one of those is tapped or any other button is tapped

```
- (void)clearAllTextFields {
    for (UITextField *textField in [self textFields]) { //textFields is an rray that is holding pointers to your 16 text fields
        [textField setText:nil];
    }
}
```

If you want this to happen on a button press or something, add it as a target.  Here is how you would do it if one of the `x`'s in the fields are tapped:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self clearAllTextFields];
    return YES;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,44)] autorelease];
[button setTitle:@"blah forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clearAllTextFields) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Hi,
I added the code but have errors,am I missing something? Should I add a IBOutlet for the button and synthesize,also "blah" should be the title of the button? Thanks for your help with this

patrick

Comment: No you dont need IBOutlet unless you are using NIBs. Blah is the title. I suggest reading the Apple iPhone Developers Guide as you start your way down the path of iPhone development.